# Oscillating vibration when turning at highway speed

Tags: steering, vibration

I have a rear drive car that has a vibration at highway speeds when turning right. The vibration is high-ish frequency and oscillates (kind of a wooo-wooo-wooo feeling/sound). It's not detectable at slow speeds or moving straight. How best to diagnose the source? Is it likely a wheel bearing? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!